# Cómo Dinamizar un ID de un SELECT

Tags: javascript, php, select, id

Tengo el siguiente SCRIPT que me permite agregar una fila nueva en la tabla al darle click a un boton, sin embargo, he podido dinamizar los ID de todos los INPUT en funcion de $t pero no he sabido como hacerlo con el SELECT que se genera a partir de PHP y una base de datos.

aqui les coloco mi codigo:

```
<script>
    
    var $t = 2;
    
    function insertarFila() {   
        let tblDatos = document.getElementById('importe').insertRow($t);
        let col1 = tblDatos.insertCell(0);
        let col2 = tblDatos.insertCell(1);
        let col3 = tblDatos.insertCell(2);
        let col4 = tblDatos.insertCell(3);
        let col5 = tblDatos.insertCell(4);
        let col6 = tblDatos.insertCell(5);

        col1.innerHTML =  $t;

    <?php
        // Código PHP que genera el select
        $selectHTML = '<select class="form-control" name="material" id="material" style="display: inline;"><option value="0" selected="selected">Elija una Opción</option>';
        $sucursales = "SELECT * FROM material_bd ORDER BY desc_mat ASC";
        $res_sucursales = mysqli_query($con, $sucursales);
        $tam = mysqli_num_rows($res_sucursales);        
        while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($res_sucursales)){
            $selectHTML .= '<option value="' . $datos['1'] . '">' . $datos['1'] . '</option>';}
        $selectHTML .= '</select>';
        echo "col2.innerHTML = '$selectHTML';";
    ?>
        col3.innerHTML = '<input id="bruto' + $t + '" type="text" class="form-control numero">';
        col4.innerHTML = '<input id="tara' + $t + '" type="text" class="form-control numero">';
        col5.innerHTML = '<input id="neto' + $t + '" type="text" class="form-control numero">';
        col6.innerHTML = '<input id="costousd' + $t + '" type="text" class="form-control numero">';

        $t++;
    }
    

</script>
```

con ese codigo me permite ingresar todo perfecto, solo que el select mantiene el mismo ID y no me sirve! hice otra codigo y no se ejecuta el script, no se cual sea el problema, aqui el otro codigo para dinamizar el ID del select en funcion de $t

```
$selectHTML = '<select class="form-control" name="material'.$t.'" id="material'.$t.'" style="display: inline;"><option value="0" selected="selected">Elija una Opción</option>';
```

Con ese ultimo codigo, no se ejecuta la funcion y no se agregan las filas nuevas!

Comment: Si esto `var $t = 2;` es una variable de `JavaScript`, el símbolo `$` es innecesario. 

También te sugiero usar `ajax` o `fetch` para consultar los datos de manera asíncrona, esto te facilita el trabajo y evita mezclar contextos en un mismo archivo. Además, puedes maquetar la fila completa del lado del servidor y retornarla a `JS` para que la agregue al `HTML` con el método `append()`.